# My SQL set permissions

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysql-error-1064

I am setting a permission on a *mysql database* as:

```
GRANT SELECT ON 'Whats-uav-u-100176'.* to "wvico-zag-u-100787"
```

But I get this error:

> ‍‍#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''Whats-uav-u-100176'.* to "wvico-zag-u-100787"' at line 1

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you mean `GRANT ALL` rather than `GRANT SELECT`?

Comment: No I don't want this user to do any editing, just select

Comment: To see the grant for a user `SELECT sql_grants FROM common_schema.sql_show_grants WHERE user='app';`

Answer (score 0):

Using SELECT option for GRANT I think you need to indicate the column list

```
GRANT SELECT (column_list) ON 'Whats-uav-u-100176'.* to "wvico-zag-u-100787"
```

Comment: Nope my host sent This is the SQL query that you need to run: GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `DATABASE`.* to "USERNAME" but i dont want this user to update etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT SELECT ON Whats-uav-u-100176.* TO wvico-zag-u-100787@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

If you want more than one access.

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON Whats-uav-u-100176.* TO wvico-zag-u-100787@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is OK except If SQL_MODE is set to ANSI_QUOTES on your server.

> **ANSI_QUOTES**
>
> Treat `"` as an identifier quote character (like the ` quote character)
>   and not as a string quote character. You can still use ` to quote
>   identifiers with this mode enabled. With ANSI_QUOTES enabled, you
>   cannot use double quotation marks to quote literal strings, because it
>   is interpreted as an identifier.

Try with single quotes

```
GRANT SELECT ON 'Whats-uav-u-100176'.* to 'wvico-zag-u-100787'
```